# thingsboard is not changing the logo

Tags: maven, spring-boot, svg, thingsboard

I can't change thingsboard logo

1. I delete the logo
2. I uploaded another one et it is svg file and it is correct(it can be read by navigator)
3. I gave it another name
4. I gave it the name by default
5. I made git clean -fdx
   6.I restarted the service thingsboard

any help???

Answer (score 0):

if you change the thingsboard logo, you must assure that the svg file that you are using doesn't have xml at its headers, otherwise it won't work or it will take you to a fallback white label page. For example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="550.801px" height="550.801px" viewBox="0 0 550.801 550.801" style="enable-background:new 0 0 550.801 550.801;"
  xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M488.426,197.019H475.2v-63.816c0-0.398-0.063-0.799-0.116-1.202c-0.021-2.534-0.827-5.023-2.562-6.995L366.325,3.694
  c-0.032-0.031-0.063-0.042-0.085-0.076c-0.633-0.707-1.371-...
```

Would change into

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="550.801px" height="550.801px" viewBox="0 0 550.801 550.801" style="enable-background:new 0 0 550.801 550.801;"
  xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M488.426,197.019H475.2v-63.816c0-0.398-0.063-0.799-0.116-1.202c-0.021-2.534-0.827-5.023-2.562-6.995L366.325,3.694
  c-0.032-0.031-0.063-0.042-0.085-0.076c-0.633-0.707-1.371-...
```

I hope my answer has been useful for you (: